# Creating an overlay popup

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, popup

I want to create an in-window pop up that darkens the entire window with a semi-transparent black overlay and there is a popup in the middle that warns the user about something. I have seen something like this on att web site

http://www.att.com/wireless/iphone/?wtSlotClick=1-003G93!CIWM01-3-1&rel=nofollow

and if you click on the order now button it will give a pop up and darkens the entire window. I know very little of javascript (close to 0) and I am currently using Rails to find the answer. Does anyone know a quick way for me to achieving this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using prototype and don't want to roll your own, check out the excellent http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/lightview/. note that it will cost you 50 bucks, but its probably the nicest implementation I have seen

If you don't mind including jquery, I usually use http://defunkt.github.com/facebox/ when I need similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/08/22/create-a-lightbox-effect-only-with-css-no-javascript-needed/

That are called lightboxes, and can be done using only CSS (but if you want it activated onclick then javascript is required).

Comment: There are also solutions that are rails-specific, ie. http://code.google.com/p/rb-lightbox-plugin/.

Comment: but this is supposed to be for a dialog box. when i was looking at lightbox i think this implementation is best used for images only? let me know if im wrong.

Comment: We you can certainly style the lightbox differently, thats up to you. Just place your form in it, they are functionally equivalent.